# Will Delphi XE 6 Android application in older versions of Android OS.?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi XE 6 version and I have created Android Application and when i'm trying to run that application in Emulator, the application is running in Android 4.3 and that application is not running in the lower versions of the Emulator. Is it possible to make the android application run in lower version of Android OS by changing any of the setting. And I didn't test by running the application in mobile phones. Currently I'm i have tested the application in Emulators(Default emulator, BlueStacks and Greymotion). Please suggest me the good solution.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi XE6 supports Android 2.3.3-2.3.7, 4.0.3, 4.0.3, 4.1.x-4.4.x. [Feature matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf)

ARMv7 + NEON FPU support is required. [Frequently asked questions](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Check the **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** settings of the [**uses-sdk** tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) in the AndroidManifest.xml file of your project.  If your **minSdkVersion** number is higher than the API level of your emulated device then your app will not run.

Note that these settings use [API Level Numbers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels), rather than Android version numbers.